# Want to differentiate between two Date/Time fields without involvement of second

Tags: reporting, datetime, filters

I have one scenario where I have to display cases in report whose **lastmodifieddate is greater than closeddate**
So everything is working fine but there is one issue
I have a case and I closed it. In my salesforce backend
the **closeddate is 2022-01-17T10:04:50.000+0000** and the lastmodifieddate is **2022-01-17T10:04:51.000+0000**

It is giving me 1-sec difference which fulfilling my condition but it's wrong.
So I want to compare these two fields without involving seconds in report.
Anyone has any idea please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have create the custom formula and has solved the problem.

```
IF(
    AND(
        DATEVALUE(LAST_UPDATEONLY) == DATEVALUE(CLOSED_DATEONLY),
        HOUR(TIMEVALUE(LAST_UPDATEONLY)) == HOUR(TIMEVALUE(CLOSED_DATEONLY)),
        MINUTE(TIMEVALUE(LAST_UPDATEONLY)) == MINUTE(TIMEVALUE(CLOSED_DATEONLY)),
        SECOND(TIMEVALUE(LAST_UPDATEONLY)) != SECOND(TIMEVALUE(CLOSED_DATEONLY))
    ), 
    1 , 
    0
)
```

Comment: If you made this a checkbox (formula) field, I imagine it (and your report filters) could be simplified. That'd allow you to remove the `IF()` entirely, and remove the comparison against the seconds. The formula would end up telling you if the datetimes are the same down to the minute, and your report filter would simply be "is this formula field true".

Answer (score 0):

Since you are comparing two "datetime" fields in your report, it is taking into consideration the time. Way to get around this will be to compare 2 date fields instead. Since lastmodifieddate is a datetime field, you can use a formula to only store the date and then compare that with your closedate field.

Comment: I've downvoted this because I think it misses the mark. OP wants to still compare the time portion, just without the "seconds" bit. So if both datetimes have a time portion of 10:40 (10:40:50 and 10:40:51), they should be treated as the "same time".

Answer (score 0):

The one case that I can see where your (Abishek Saxena) answer won't work is if you experience this 1 second difference between `LastModifiedDate` and `ClosedDate` on a minute boundary.

A difference between those two fields should be rare enough as is, and a difference across a minute boundary should be rarer still. So with that in mind, it may not make sense to put more effort into this.

However, I think there's a simpler approach that will end up being more accurate.

**Formulas allow us to add/subtract with datetimes**, so if you simply subtract your two datetime fields and check to see if the difference is greater than some threshold you should end up with what you want.

`(LastModifiedDate - ClosedDate) > 0.0000116`

Subtracting datetimes gives you a decimal result, and is based on the number of seconds between the two datetimes.
Whole number part = number of complete days in the difference
Decimal part = remaining number of seconds / 86400 (the number of seconds in a day)

So if you want to find if your two datetimes are within X seconds of eachother, the number you want to compare against is `X / 86400`, for 1 second that's roughly 0.00001157407.